# inet_pton replacement function for php 5.2.17 in windows

Tags: php, windows, ipv6, replace

On a [replacement alternative for inet_pton()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php#59714) in PHP, the following code is given:

```
<?php
function inet_pton($ip)
{
    # ipv4
    if (strpos($ip, '.') !== FALSE) {
        $ip = pack('N',ip2long($ip));
    }
    # ipv6
    elseif (strpos($ip, ':') !== FALSE) {
        $ip = explode(':', $ip);
        $res = str_pad('', (4*(8-count($ip))), '0000', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        foreach ($ip as $seg) {
            $res .= str_pad($seg, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
        $ip = pack('H'.strlen($res), $res);
    }
    return $ip;
}
?>
```

But when testing this using the following test code, it shows that not all entries are correct:

```
<?php
$arrIPs = array(
        "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334",
        "fe80:01::af0",
        "::af0",
        "192.168.0.1",
        "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:192.168.0.1");
foreach($arrIPs as $strIP) {
    $strResult = bin2hex(inet_pton($strIP));
    echo "From: {$strIP} to: {$strResult}<br />\n";
}
/*
From: 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334 to: 20010db885a3000000008a2e03707334
From: fe80:01::af0 to: 0000000000000000fe80000100000af0 //Incorrect
From: ::af0 to: 00000000000000000000000000000af0
From: 192.168.0.1 to: c0a80001
From: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:192.168.0.1 to: 00000000 //Incorrect
*/
?>
```

I don't know about the correct IPv6 syntax, so I prefer if someone else, who knows more about IPv6 and standards, looks at this and tells me what's wrong with it?

Comment: I don't really understand the last paragraph. What is it about PEAR that forces you to stay on PHP 5.2? Why can't you just upgrade to PHP 5.3? (bear in mind also that PHP 5.2 has been unsupported for two years; it is badly out of date now)

Comment: @SDC Apparently the 5.3 does not come with PEAR for windows. Please do tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: And also: the function you show above is terribly wrong. It only expands `::` correctly if the address starts with it. It incorrectly interprets i.e. `2001:db8::1` as `::2001:db8:0:1`.

Comment: PEAR is a pretty standard part of PHP's software ecosystem. It is available with all versions of PHP on all platforms. In any case, PEAR itself is not much more than an installer platform for other software; most of the software installed by PEAR could be installed without it if necessary (a lot of PHP software these days uses Composer or PHAR to install rather than PEAR, but that's nothing to do with the PHP version they're using)

Comment: @SDC Can you imagine that I've worked for a company who was selling 1000... of debian lenny servers with php 5.2 on board? Are you willing to upgrade this - working - servers remotely? 'Upgrade your PHP version' is mostly an imaginal hint. Nothing worth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do it right:

```
function inet_pton($ip){
    # ipv4
    if (strpos($ip, '.') !== FALSE) {
        if (strpos($ip, ':') === FALSE) $ip = pack('N',ip2long($ip));
        else {
            $ip = explode(':',$ip);
            $ip = pack('N',ip2long($ip[count($ip)-1]));
        }
    }
    # ipv6
    elseif (strpos($ip, ':') !== FALSE) {
        $ip = explode(':', $ip);
        $parts=8-count($ip);
        $res='';$replaced=0;
        foreach ($ip as $seg) {
            if ($seg!='') $res .= str_pad($seg, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            elseif ($replaced==0) {
                for ($i=0;$i<=$parts;$i++) $res.='0000';
                $replaced=1;
            } elseif ($replaced==1) $res.='0000';
        }
        $ip = pack('H'.strlen($res), $res);
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Results:

```
From: 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334 to:
string '20010db885a3000000008a2e03707334' (length=32)

From: fe80:01::af0 to:
string 'fe800001000000000000000000000af0' (length=32)

From: ::af0 to:
string '00000000000000000000000000000af0' (length=32)

From: 192.168.0.1 to:
string 'c0a80001' (length=8)

From: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:192.168.0.1 to:
string 'c0a80001' (length=8)
```

Comment: It worked very nicely with some existing code! Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, just remember it will always pick IPv4 when presented with a double format IPv6.

Answer (score 4):

I just downloaded the PHP 5.3 installer from [php.net](http://php.net/) and it has PEAR included in the installer. It's just not installed by default:

[image: PHP 5.3 PEAR install option]

Comment: Hmm maybe that's why I had trouble finding the manual install of PEAR, you are prompted and expected to install it when you install PHP. Ok, so I should reinstall PHP, but it doesn't solve the question though... I'll give you +1 for finding this out for me

Comment: @FlorianMertens I really don't understand why the question is still open. You can upgrade PHP and use the built in inet_pton() function. Why are you searching for a PHP 5.2 solution?

Comment: @FlorianMertens Don't understand me wrong. I know that there are several reasons to use PHP 5.2. (in constrast to most of the answerers on SO ) .. Tell me a reason and you'll get your function

Comment: @hek2mgl What if someone is developing a site for 5.3 or uptodate live server but only has access to a small virtual pre-live account on a server with 5.2.* installed, to test or demonstrate his code to a business manager? Could be an internal network server, they can be less updated.
This is one reason, but there are others. I for example, don't install php 5.3 atm, simply because from experience, it was a struggle to change versions, and I _PREFER_ or _CANT_ upgrade due to project time constraints being very small. Etc etc...

Comment: A good reason would be: "We have deployed our software to (expected) many customers who are potentially not willing or able to update their server's OS. But I really, really need this function." If you just need a PHP5.3 test environment, consider to install VirtualBox.